# How do you interpolate UV mapping coords in a quad tessellation evaluation shader?

Tags: opengl, texture, glsl, uv-mapping

Does anyone know who to interpolate UVs in a quad tessellation evaluation shader? I can interpolate the position easily like so :

```
vec4 p1 = mix(gl_in[0].gl_Position,
        gl_in[1].gl_Position,
        gl_TessCoord.x);
vec4 p2 = mix(gl_in[2].gl_Position,
        gl_in[3].gl_Position,
        gl_TessCoord.x);
gl_Position = mix(p2, p1, gl_TessCoord.y);
```

But I can't figure out how to interpolate the incoming UV coordinates. I need to do so to pass them on to the fragment shader.

With perfect quad UVs from 0 to 1, I can use `gl_TessCoord.xy`. Unfortunately that doesn't work when the UVs aren't mapped 1:1 to a texture.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was else-where, the same interpolation works for UV coords.

```
vec2 uv1 = mix(teUv[0], teUv[1], gl_TessCoord.x);
vec2 uv2 = mix(teUv[2], teUv[3], gl_TessCoord.x);
fUv = mix(uv2, uv1, gl_TessCoord.y);
```